# Register Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, email-client, google-oauth

I downloaded an open source project  about an IOS app which you can send and receive Email[like Gmail application on phone],the programmer used Google OAuth 2.0.
my question is "in order to use Google OAuth 2.0,an app must be registered,how can i register  that app?"

Thanks for your  answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer,in order to use Google API,have to sign in this website[console.developers.google.com],and register your product.After registering,Google gives you valid client ID.